# How to make a new column of numpy arrays in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'a': ['on', 'on', 'off', 'off'],
                   'b': ['on', 'off', 'on', 'off']})
```

How can I create a new column `df['new']` with the type of NumPy arrays/lists so that I can perform operations like:

```py
df.loc[1, 'new'] = np.array([2 , 'l'])
#or
df.loc[1, 'new'] = [2 , 'l']
```

Comment: Do you really want arrays as opposed to lists?  An `object` dtype array column can hold anything - array, list, dict, string, None`

Comment: @hpaulj list is fine for me as well

Comment: Why do you need to "declare" the type of object you are putting in a `dataframe`? Just put it there.

Comment: @Aryerez I thought so at first, but I was getting the following error when I do it directly:`ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the datatype as "object" while creating the new column and then insert the elements as needed:

```
df["new"] = pd.Series(dtype="object")
df.at[1, 'new'] = [2 , 'l']
>>> df
   id    a    b     new
0   1   on   on     NaN
1   2   on  off  [2, l]
2   3  off   on     NaN
3   4  off  off     NaN
```